# requestLocationUpdates with PendingIntent and Broadcast - what broadcasts do I get

Tags: android, gps, android-pendingintent, location-provider

I have setup an alarm which is received by a BroadcastReceiver which launches a WakefulIntentService (class `LocationMonitor`). In the `LocationMonitor` I have :

```
private static final int MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SCANS = 1 * 30 * 1000;
private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 0;

@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    final CharSequence action = intent.getAction();
    if (action == null) { // monitor command from the alarm manager
        // the call below enables the LocationReceiver
        BaseReceiver.enable(this, ENABLE, LocationReceiver.class);
        if (lm == null) lm = (LocationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NOT_USED, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SCANS, MIN_DISTANCE, pi);
    } else if (ac_location_data.equals(action)) {
        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            final Location loc = (Location) extras
                    .get(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
            if (loc == null) {
                w("NULL LOCATION  - EXTRAS : " + extras); //Log.w
                // while gps is disabled I keep getting this :
                // NULL LOCATION - EXTRAS : Bundle[{providerEnabled=false}]
            } else {
                final double lon = loc.getLongitude();
                final double lat = loc.getLatitude();
                w("latitude :" + lat + " -- longitude : " + lon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have several issues with the code above.

1. If GPS is **initially disabled and then I enable it** I get a bunch of `W/GpsLocationProvider(...): Unneeded remove listener for uid 1000`. The warning comes from [here](http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/frameworks/base/location/java/com/android/internal/location/GpsLocationProvider.java#838). I can't find in the code *where is this removing of listeners triggered*, *nor can I see where they are assigned the uid 1000* ([apparently](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Android_uids_and_guids) the system server).
2. When I enable the gps I get the location as expected and then a "RemoteException"

   > LocationManagerService(...): RemoteException calling onLocationChanged on Receiver{4083ee68 Intent PendingIntent{4084e6b8: PendingIntentRecord{4083ef78 gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android broadcastIntent}}}mUpdateRecords: {gps=UpdateRecord{40838180 mProvider: gps mUid: 10064}}

   which is not really a RemoteException, just a PendingIntent.CancelledException - the message is quite misleading. Or so I think : it comes from [here](http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java#1498) which calls [this](http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java#309). *My question is* : why is it reusing the Intent - shouldn't the FLAG_ONE_SHOT dispose of it ?

But the most important question is : *when I register a PendingIntent like this **what intents do I expect to receive*** ? *And what flags should I use* ?

Keep in mind I am using this pattern cause I want to have the phone update its position *even when asleep* and this achieves it (I do get the location updates). I try to simulate `requestSingleUpdate` (unavailable in 2.3) using `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`.

Receiver :

```
public final class LocationReceiver extends BaseReceiver {

    private static final Class<? extends Monitor> MONITOR_CLASS =
        LocationMonitor.class;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        d(intent.toString());
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        d(action + "");
        final Intent i = new Intent(context, MONITOR_CLASS);
        i.fillIn(intent, 0); // TODO do I need flags ?
        i.setAction(ac_location_data.toString());
        WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To this question:

> when I register a PendingIntent like this what intents do I expect to
>   receive ? And what flags should I use ?

When you register for location updates and pass a `PendingIntent`, this `PendingIntent` will be triggered when the `LocationManager` decides to inform you about a location update. You can provide pretty much whatever you want, depending on what you want to happen when the `PendingIntent` is triggered. The `LocationManager` will add an extra to the `Intent` that is sent. This extra has the bundle key `LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED` and the object associated with that key is a `Location` object.

`LocationManager` will use this `PendingIntent` again and again to inform your app of location updates, so I think using `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` is probably not such a good idea. If you only want a single update, why don't you just unregister after you get one update?

**EDIT: Add code to cancel any previously requested updates before registering for updates**

Before you call `registerLocationUpdates()`, do this to cancel any previously registered updates:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
    // Get any existing matching PendingIntent
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NOT_USED, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if (pi != null) {
        // Cancel any updates for this PendingIntent, because we are about to
        //  invalidate it
        lm.removeUpdates(pi);
    }
    // Create a new PendingIntent and cancel any previous one
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NOT_USED, i,
                  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    // Now register for location updates...
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_SCANS, MIN_DISTANCE, pi);
```

**NOTE:** Actually, I don't know why you need to cancel any previous `PendingIntent` and create a new one in this case. You can just get a `PendingIntent` and if you have already registered for location updates with that `PendingIntent`, I don't think that registering again will cause the `PendingIntent` to be used multiple times. If you want to try that, all you need to do is to remove `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` from your existing code. I think that is a better/cleaner/clearer solution.

Comment: Thanks ! The code above is triggered by the alarm manager on a periodic basis and since the location updates can take some time I do wander if unregistering will mess it up (how are consecutive registrations handled ?). What sure messes this up is the `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` - the other parts of the question is me trying to understand exactly why

Comment: `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` just means that any matching `PendingIntent` should be invalidated (ie: canceled) and a new one created with the supplied parameters, flags, extras, etc.

Comment: Ah...you are registering  for location updates repeatedly and canceling the previous `PendingIntent`. That means that the `LocationManager` has a request for callbacks, and when it tries to send the callback the `PendingIntent` is no longer valid.

Comment: You should call `removeUpdates()` with the previous `PendingIntent` before calling `requestLocationUpdates()` with the new on. I'll add some example code to my answer.

Comment: I added code to my answer. While doing that I realized that you aren't actually changing the `PendingIntent` in any way when you cancel the previous one and create a new one, so I added another (simpler) suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot - will be going through your answer in detail ASAP. Please follow the links I posted to the android code - do you understand why those exceptions ? EDIT : canceling the intent results in "remoteException" I believe (which is not a remoteExc really) - I mean using the CANCEL flag. Wont be able to check all this till tomorrowish

Comment: Yes, you are right. The message `RemoteException calling onLocationChanged on ...` isn't really a remote exception. It would be a remote exception if it was calling back a listener, but this is actually the result of the `PendingIntent` no longer being valid. Your analysis is correct. If you apply my suggested changes and replace `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` with a call to `removeUpdates()` you won't get any more of these exceptions.